# Can DPDK applications be written in c++ and if so, how is it done?

Tags: c++, c, dpdk

Hello people of the Internet,

instead of writing a DPDK application in C I want to use C++. Is there a way to do so?

I probably should mention that configuring, compiling and setting up DPDK itself and everything related to it (binding NICs,...) works perfectly fine. As well as compiling and running the example applications and my own applications written in C. However, I want to use some of my own C++ classes from another project in a new DPDK application and therefore it would be very nice to use C++ instead of C.

Thank you.

Comment: extern "C" {/*prototypes*/} https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp

Answer (score 5):

DPDK is ready to mix with C++ code, since each DPDK header already have:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Source: http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/common/include/rte_eal.h#n49

There are also many open source projects written in C++ and using DPDK. To name a few:

- TRex: https://github.com/cisco-system-traffic-generator/trex-core
- MoonGen: https://github.com/emmericp/MoonGen

So please have a look how exactly the DPDK get integrated with a C++ code in one of those projects.